# Trying to get the first 5 characters of input 1, and first character of input 2

Tags: jquery, if-statement, string-length

I am trying to generate usernames for users based on the exisiting manual formula we use: first 5 characters of last name, first initial of first name.

Simple:

```
$("#first_name, #last_name").keyup(function(){
    var a = $("#first_name").val().substring(0, 1),
        b = $("#last_name").val().substring(0, 5);

    $("#username").val(b+a);
});
```

However, I have been trying to figure out the rules for when the last name is less than 5 characters, and then fill those missing characters with the next letters of their first name. And lastly if the first + last name is less than 5 characters in total, just add them.

This was something along the lines I was working towards, but it wasn't working and I can't seem to logic why:

```
$("#first_name, #last_name").keyup(function(){

    var a = $("#first_name").val(),
        b = $("#last_name").val();

    if( b < 5 ) {

        var c = ( 5 - b.length );

        if( c > a.length ) {
            var d = a.substring(0, c);
            $("#username").val( b + d );
        } else {

            $("#username").val( b + a );
        }

    } else {

        $("#username").val( b + a );

    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been trying to figure out the rules...

The key here is the last name. You have only 2 cases, and it depends on the last name length.

When you know it is less than 5 chars. Use it as is!
And use it's length to calculate how many chars to use from the first name.

```js
$("#first_name, #last_name").keyup(function(){

  var a = $("#first_name").val(),
      b = $("#last_name").val();

  // Last name longer than 5 chars
  if( b.length >= 5 ) {
    a = a.substr(0,1);
    b = b.substr(0,5);
    
  // Last name shorter than 5 chars
  }else{
    a = a.substr(0,(5-b.length+1));  // That is at least 1 + 5 possible "replacements"...
  }

  $("#username").val( b + a );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

First name: <input type="text" id="first_name"><br/>
Last name:  <input type="text" id="last_name"><br>
username: <input "type="text" id="username">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last name is less than 5, concatenate the two together and take the first 6.

If the lastname is greater than 5, take the first 5 of the last name plus the first character of the first name.

```js
$("#first_name, #last_name").keyup(function(){
    var a = $("#first_name").val().trim().toLowerCase().replace( / /g, ''),
        b = $("#last_name").val().trim().toLowerCase().replace( / /g, ''),
        c = '';
    
    if (!a || !b) return;
    
    if ( b < 5 ) {
        c = (b + a).substring(0, 6);
    } else {
        c = b.substring(0, 5) + a[0];
    }
    
    $("#username").val( c );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" value="" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
<div><input type="text" id="username"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for that, but it doesn't seem to work for users with the name of say: Ana Ng where it should output "ngana" instead of "nga"

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv Added the `toLowerCase()` and removing spaces.